# My swap program is not working using Template?

Tags: c++, templates, swap

I'm using `Template` keyword to run simple swap program, Kindly help me why my program is not working out?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void Swap(T m, T n)
{
    T temp;

    temp = m;
    m = n;
    n = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 5, j = 6;

    cout << "Before swapping:" << endl;
    cout << i << " and " << j << endl;

    Swap(i, j);

    cout << "After Swapping:" << endl;
    cout << i << " and " << j << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: You're passing the args by value not as a reference, as such your passed params are never modified, your signature should be `void Swap(T& m, T& n)`

Comment: If you think the problem is related to templates, try without the templates and see.

Comment: Dude your name is @Bjarne stroustoup and asking such question :P

Comment: @RupeshYadav. well his name *is* full of typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating copies of your arguments because you are taking them by value. If you want to update them within the function you should take them by reference:

```
void Swap(T& m, T& n)
//         ^     ^
```

Additionally, your implementation has an implicit constraint that `T` must be default-constructible, which is not necessary for swapping. You should construct your `temp` variable directly:

```
T temp = m;
```

You'd also be better off using move semantics to avoid making copies:

```
T temp(std::move(m)); // or T temp = std::move(m);
m = std::move(n);
n = std::move(temp);
```